# Show random swf banners in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, banner

I have two flash banners (.swf) and i want to show them randomly on page refresh.
I can do it with image files (using javascript), but with flash it's not working

For image files i can do this.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var HeaderImage= new Array()

HeaderImage[0]="URL-OF-HEADER-IMAGE-1";
HeaderImage[1]="URL-OF-HEADER-IMAGE-2";
var random=Math.round(2*Math.random());

document.write(&quot;<style>&quot;);
document.write(&quot;#header-wrapper {&quot;);
document.write(&#39; background:url(&quot;&#39; + HeaderImage[random] + &#39;&quot;) no-repeat left TOP;&#39;);
document.write(&quot; }&quot;);
document.write(&quot;</style>&quot;);

</script>
```

Comment: Is php an acceptable solution?

Comment: how did you do it successfully with image files?

Comment: No i want to use it in blogger.com. It must HTML and Javascript

Comment: Can you please provide examples of things that are not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SWFObject to embed the flash file and then randomly pick up the name of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getRandomFilename()
    {
        var names = ['myFile1.swf', 'myFile2.swf', 'myFile3.swf'];
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
        return names[r];
    }

    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF(getRandomFilename(), "myFlashContent", "800", "60", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myFlashContent">

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am glad I could help. Would you mind accepting the answer please?

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it with image files, you can do it with flash. Embedding flash is a bit different, however, than with image files.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="movie_name" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf"/>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="movie_name.swf" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf"/>
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

That is the embed code for flash apps.  One alternative is you can use javascript to change the parameters in there.  However, you could just as easily use iframes.

```
<iframe id="mov" src="movie.swf"></iframe>
```

Then, just use javascript to change the src value to the path to your flash movie.